# Time difference and convert into hours and minutes in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I am having the time values as follows
starttime like : 09:00:00 , 
endTime like : 10:00:00 ;
here no date value is needed.
so this values need to calculate difference and convert into hours and minutes,seconds.

I had tried with :

```
var test = new Date().getTime(startTime); 
var test1 = new Date().getTime(endTime);
var total = test1 - test;
```

Some time am getting `NaN` and `1111111` some digit format.

How can I convert into HH:MM:SS, or any other way to find time difference.

Comment: Use moment.js for this instead of relying on javascripts built in. It will help you loads!

Comment: hi thanks for the comment.how to use and convert the values in hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 20):

You can take a difference of the time values:

```
var diff = test1.getTime() - test.getTime(); // this is a time in milliseconds
var diff_as_date = new Date(diff);
diff_as_date.getHours(); // hours
diff_as_date.getMinutes(); // minutes
diff_as_date.getSeconds(); // seconds
```

Comment: Hi i tried with that but am getting the error as Object 1382687270743 has no method 'getTime'.The error points the places in test1.getTime().please help me how to solve the problem.

Comment: you should be using `test = new Date(startTime)` and `test1 = new Date(endTime)`

Comment: if am using the before you had suggested again am getting error while printing the diff.getHours() as  Object NaN has no method 'getHours' .how to solve the problem.

Comment: If `new Date(startTime)` is giving you an error, try `test = new Date('1970-01-01 ' + startTime)`

Comment: hi again am getting error as Object NaN has no method 'getHours'  while am using new Date('1970-01-01' + startTime) like that.please help me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.it must be  something like below right?               diff_as_date.getHours(); // hours
    diff_as_date.getMinutes(); // minutes    diff_as_date.getSeconds(); // seconds

Comment: Another issue I've faced is that the `new Date(diff)` returned date with the timezone offset (in my case, 3 hours). I used `getUTCHours()`, `getUTCMinutes()` and `getUTCSeconds()` to get the right values.

Answer (score 10):

```js
    var startTime = "09:00:00";
    var endTime = "10:30:00";
    
    var todayDate = moment(new Date()).format("MM-DD-YYYY"); //Instead of today date, We can pass whatever date        

    var startDate = new Date(`${todayDate} ${startTime}`);
    var endDate = new Date(`${todayDate } ${endTime}`);
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(startDate.getTime() - endDate.getTime());

    var hh = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000 / 60 / 60);   
    hh = ('0' + hh).slice(-2)
   
    timeDiff -= hh * 1000 * 60 * 60;
    var mm = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000 / 60);
    mm = ('0' + mm).slice(-2)

    timeDiff -= mm * 1000 * 60;
    var ss = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
    ss = ('0' + ss).slice(-2)
    
    alert("Time Diff- " + hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.28.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hi thanks for the comments.but in declaration var startDate = new Date("January 1, 1970 " + startTime); in this declaration with out giving date how to calculate.please help me

Comment: hi hongchae. how difference the two different times.for sample time1 = 02:45 and time2 = 00:55. this is i need to minius the times and convert into hours and mintues.can any one help me. i had tried with var sp = time1.split(":"); var sp1 = time2.split(":"); var th = sp[0];var tm = sp[1]; var tth = sp1[0];var ttm = spl[1]; var finalh = 1 * sp[0] - 1 * sp1[0]; var finalmin = 1 * sp[1] - 1 * sp1[1]; this working fine if the minutes sp greater than sp1 but other cases am getting minus values as minutes . how to convert the values into hours and minutes.please help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
function diff(start, end) {
start = start.split(":");
end = end.split(":");
var startDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, start[0], start[1], 0);
var endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, end[0], end[1], 0);
var diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
var hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
var minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);

// If using time pickers with 24 hours format, add the below line get exact hours
if (hours < 0)
   hours = hours + 24;

return (hours <= 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes <= 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in `var timeDiff = Math.abs(startDate.getTime() - endDate.getTime());`
we do not get the sign `-`, if `endDate.getTime()` is greater.
how we can get the sign to?